# Delay for my pdf download in laravel using barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Tags: laravel

I am using barryvdh/laravel-dompdf for my pdf download in laravel.The download is ok but it takes nearly2-3 mins for the download.What could be the issue?

I have seen when i try to include my logo in the pdf it becomes slower.

```
<a style="margin-left: -100px;" class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}"><img align="center" style="display: inline;" src="{{url('/img/favicon.png')}}">{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                    </a>
```

Comment: This library uses a lot of data to generate the email on the server. To make this process faster you just need a better server or put less data in your pdf / optimize this. If you want for instance a faster way to create PDF's I suggest using a library like http://pdfmake.org/#/ which will generate a lot of data on the client.

Comment: i have seen when i include the logo in my pdf then its slower.               <a style="margin-left: -100px;" class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}"><img align="center" style="display: inline;" src="{{url('/img/favicon.png')}}">{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                    </a>

Comment: It requires more resources to generate an image so that explains why the load time will increase. Had a type in above comment i meant `generate the pdf on the server`.